# Tamanhos diferente para imagens destacadas no wordpress!

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou com um problema e não sei como resolve-lo já tentei de tudo e nada!

Tenho um tema que usa 3 imagens diferentes para a imagem destacada, estou usando o `add_image_size` para gerar esses três tamanhos de imagem, mais o problema é que toda a imagem que faço upload ele gera os 3 tamanhos!

Se eu postar uma galeria, vai ser gerada 3 tamanhos de imagens diferentes para cada imagem e isso está consumindo demais meu servidor. Preciso que ele gere apenas 3 imagens da imagem em destaque.

Teria como fazer isso?

segue meu codigo do functions com add imagem size:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    add_image_size('ultimas-capa', 370, 240, true);
    add_image_size('capa-interno', 1020, 300, true);
    add_image_size('blog-capa', 780, 300, true);
}

if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ){
    $content_width = 800;
}

add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'curioso_image_sizes');
function curioso_image_sizes($sizes) {

$mythemesizes = array(
    'blog-capa' => __('Imagem Postagem')
);

$sizes = array_merge($sizes, $mythemesizes);
return $sizes;
```

Answer (score 2):

O seu código parece-me que está incompleto. Vou basear minha resposta em cima do que eu entendi.

1. Add Image Size

   Esse método faz o que o nome dele diz: adiciona um tamanho novo de imagem. Qualquer imagem é uma imagem, incluindo as imagens em destaque. Você adiciona suporte à [thumbnails](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support), e depois adiciona 3 novos tamanhos para imagens, independente do fato delas serem thumbs ou não. Essas duas ações são coisas independentes. Adicionar tamanhos diferentes pra imagens pode ser feito sem os thumbs estarem ativados. O [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/), na verdade, está agindo exatamente como deveria. Se você quer adicionar um tamanho exclusivo para os thumbs, o WP tem um método pra isso.
2. Set Post Thumbnail Size

   Como o nome diz, [esse método](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_post_thumbnail_size/) seta o tamanho do thumbnail. Se você ver o fonte desse método, vai ver que

   ```
   function set_post_thumbnail_size( $width = 0, $height = 0, $crop = false ) {
       add_image_size( 'post-thumbnail', $width, $height, $crop );
   }
   ```

   O parâmetro `post_thumbnail` faz exatamente a filtragem que (eu acho que) você procura. Você pode incluir esse parâmetro no seu código, ou usar o método acima (o que eu acho mais inteligente, pois o tornará mais legível)

Acredito que isso solucione o seu problema. Como disse, o código parece-me incompleto. [Aqui](https://slocumthemes.com/2014/05/adjust-set-size-featured-image-size-wordpress/) tem um artigo relativamente velho, mas que tem boas informações sobre o assunto.